# How to build and Run Storm Topology within Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-storm

I followed Storm Starter instructions and imported Twitter Storm in IntelliJ. For sake of testing I edited *ExclaimationToplogy* a bit and used following Maven command to build and run it:

```
mvn -f m2-pom.xml compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

But I am more interested to build and run within IDE rather than from command line. What actions do I need to perform?

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Follow the steps in storm-starter's: [Using storm-starter with IntelliJ IDEA](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter#intellij-idea)
2. Open Maven's `pom.xml` file and remove `<scope>provided</scope>` line from storm dependency. This enables IntelliJ to compile storm dependency on build.
3. Go to `/src/jvm/storm/starter/`, right click on ExclamationTopology file and `Run 'ExclamationTop....main()'`

Comment: Amazing Sir! It really sorted it out!

Comment: This should be written in the documentation about using Intellij Idea.

Comment: This works, but then to deploy to the cluster you still need `provided` in the pom file. Is there an way to have maven do this automatically?

Comment: @Andrew, you can use system property in your POM file, e.g. `<scope>${storm.scope}</scope>` and then use `-Dstorm.scope=provided` option when submitting to the cluster. If you don't set this option `<scope>` is ignored.

Comment: This works and lets me build storm and storm started within intellij. Intellij still highlights classes defined in clojure as not resolved. (eg `backtype.storm.LocalCluster`),  but Intellij is able to correctly resolve the java  classes (eg `backtype.storm.ILocalCluster`) . I wonder if this is a bug in intellij , or is there another config to tweak ?  ( I am running IntelliJ 14, Ultimate edition, which includes Clojure plugin)

Answer (score 0):

From within IntelliJ, if you get Clojure related compiler errors involving `LocalCluster` then .... do a mvn clean install -DskipTests from the command line on the same project first. Then do a 'Rebuild Project' from within IntelliJ. Life is full of mysteries :-).

You need to also ensure that the storm-core is not in `provided` scope for storm-starter.