# ClassNotFound error when running storm-starter topologies in local mode (Win10, OS X)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, apache-storm

I'm trying to debug Storm Topology (on Storm v 1.0.0) under windows via:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
builder.setSpout("spout", new RandomIntegerSpout());
builder.setBolt("partialsum", new StatefulSumBolt("partial"), 1).shuffleGrouping("spout");
builder.setBolt("printer", new PrinterBolt(), 2).shuffleGrouping("partialsum");
builder.setBolt("total", new StatefulSumBolt("total"), 1).shuffleGrouping("printer");

Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(false);
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
StormTopology topology = builder.createTopology();
cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, topology);
```

And get the following error (WordCount/Exclamation/Stateful or other topologies from storm-starter - does not matter):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.daemon.acker
at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.javaDeserialize(Utils.java:181) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:430) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$get_task_object.invoke(task.clj:74) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data$fn__66.invoke(task.clj:177) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:930) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data.invoke(task.clj:170) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$mk_task.invoke(task.clj:181) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor$fn__6149.invoke(executor.clj:371) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.core$map$fn__4553.invoke(core.clj:2622) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:507) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$seq__4128.invoke(core.clj:137) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core.protocols$seq_reduce.invoke(protocols.clj:30) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6506.invoke(protocols.clj:101) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core.protocols$fn__6452$G__6447__6465.invoke(protocols.clj:13) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6519) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$into.invoke(core.clj:6600) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor.invoke(executor.clj:372) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__6779$exec_fn__3235__auto__$reify__6781$iter__6786__6790$fn__6791.invoke(worker.clj:634) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:507) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$seq__4128.invoke(core.clj:137) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:3009) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:3025) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__6779$exec_fn__3235__auto__$reify__6781.run(worker.clj:634) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) ~[?:1.8.0_65]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__6779$exec_fn__3235__auto____6780.invoke(worker.clj:606) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:178) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:630) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$fn__6779$mk_worker__6874.doInvoke(worker.clj:580) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:512) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__7647.invoke(supervisor.clj:1200) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:251) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$get_valid_new_worker_ids$iter__7208__7212$fn__7213.invoke(supervisor.clj:380) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:49) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.lang.RT.seq(RT.java:507) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$seq__4128.invoke(core.clj:137) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$dorun.invoke(core.clj:3009) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at clojure.core$doall.invoke(core.clj:3025) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$get_valid_new_worker_ids.invoke(supervisor.clj:367) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor$sync_processes.invoke(supervisor.clj:428) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.core$partial$fn__4527.invoke(core.clj:2492) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.storm.event$event_manager$fn__909.invoke(event.clj:40) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
```

This behaves like if there is no jar-file in workers's working directory. But according to comment ";;in local mode there is no jar" in `Nimbus.clj` it does not seems to be wrong. **In version 0.10.0 this problem does not occur**. Any ideas?

The problem occurs when I try to run a debug in Intellij using maven-exec plugin with the following command line in configuration (like recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205193/how-to-build-and-run-storm-topology-within-intellij-idea?rq=1)):

```
compile exec:java -Dstorm.topology=org.apache.storm.starter.WordCountTopology
```

from directory, where topology's POM-file is situated.

**UPD**: the problem is definetely caused by unavailability of any (topology or storm-core) classes for worker thread while it's initialization. (Trying both WordCount and Exclamation topologies illustrates this). Playings with scope of "storm-core" dependency and intellij profile in topology's POM-s gave nothing.

Comment: It is correct, that tn local mode you do not need a jar containing the user code. But maybe some storm-jars are missing in your classpath... Please double check.

Comment: I am seeing this in OS X too. I have updated a 0.10.0 topology which was running fine.

Answer (score 4):

I've been running my LocalCluster with `sbt run`, if I run it using `java -jar fatjar.jar` everything runs fine. For now I'm going to run with Intellij sorting out the classpath, no idea why `sbt` is behaving strangely when resolving the classpath. Anyone with any info please comment!

Answer (score 1):

I found some solution: use of standard Idea's building and running functionality works well for clear java topologies. But only until execution will run some shell-scripts (like splitsentece.py). Then it fails with file not found exception, so compilation without maven seems to be not fully functional